# In Linux how to reboot the system n number of times

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

I want to write a script in Linux which will reboot the system 20 times. How to write such a script?

Comment: save the number of reboots to a file

Comment: You could make a simple script in `/etc/rc.local` that would use a counter in a file like `/etc/rebootcount` and reduce it every time.  Would that be any usefull?  Certainly not, which is a good reason for no one to want to spend a minute on it.  It is also a very annoying thing to test.  If you persist in this strange idea and want help, show us what you've got so far.

Comment: Hello Hacker/Learner, which distribution you are using and what is the purpose of this task ? Accordingly, we can assist you.

Answer (score 4):

Weird request, but...

You could put something like this into `/etc/init.d/anExecutableScript`:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -f counter.txt ]; then
  echo 1 > counter.txt
  rebootcount=1
else
  rebootcount=`cat counter.txt`
fi

if [ $rebootcount -lt 20 ]; then 
  echo $((rebootcount+1)) > counter.txt
  reboot -f
else
  rm counter.txt
fi
```

Comment: not all script in init.d are executed at boot, this script might have to be linked in rcX.d (where X is run level).

Comment: I would use `-f` instead of `-d` for the test. `-d` is used to check if `FILE exists and is a directory`

Comment: Good spotting @Lambert!, I have fixed it.

Comment: `$((rebootcount++))` increases `rebootcount` but expands to its old value.  So `newcount` is actually the previous value, and `counter.txt` never exceeds 1. (Tested with bash 4.2.37, 4.3.46.)

Comment: okay, edited to get rid of `newcount` entirely. how's that?

Comment: I would also fully-path counter.txt -- who knows what directory you might get called from.